# SQL Inner Join issues in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing my first SQL and I'm having issues Updating a table with information from another one. One table has a list of AssocID's and month that I need match other information with.

```
UPDATE tblAssocReimbMonth 
INNER JOIN [Print_summary_by_account (2)] ON [tblAssocReimbMonth].[AssocID]= 
           [Print_summary_by_account (2)].[Shared Account Parent Code]
```

Then I have some SET entries where I'm just matching the information to be updated.

```
WHERE (((tblAssocReimbMonth.Month)=[Print_summary_by_account (2)].[Month]));
```

Now, I thought this should update the information where the Month's and the ID's match but whenever I run the preview in Access its only changing the month and the AssocID fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need to supply the columns and associated values you want to update. Use SET like "UPDATE tblAssocReimbMonth SET Column = Value"

Answer (score -1):

Need to use SET to update values:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Column1 = s.Column2, a.Column3 = s.Column4, ...
FROM tblAssocReimbMOnth a
INNER JOIN [Print_summary_by_account (2)] s ON a.[AssocID]= 
       s.[Shared Account Parent Code]
WHERE (((tblAssocReimbMonth.Month)=s.[Month]));
```

I also aliased your tables to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: This query is not compliant in MS Access SQL.